# SQL dialects are not visible

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have problem with creating SQL file in IntelliJ IDEA. I'm following some course. I don't have something like that:
intellij:
[image: intellij]

And also my file looks different than that from this course.
It's my SQL file icon:
my icon:
[image: my icon]

And it's SQL file icon from this course:
icon from course:
[image: icon from course]

What is wrong and how can I change dialect?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using spring boot and probably an in-memory database. In that case, you do not have to be concerned about this warning. 
Please be certain to provide database details in the properties or yaml file, as specified by the course.
And about the icon, it must be mainly due to the difference in the IntelliJ version.